# Card game vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary

I am building an online version of the [game of Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28game%29), and I want to get my vocabulary straight. So far, the words I have are "card", "deck", "(card) feature", "set", "player" and "dealer".

I am missing words describing:

- the initial laying of 12 cards (lay out? initialisation?)
- the addition of 3 cards when a set has been found (add on? filler?)
- the set of cards that are face up, on the table (board? table?)
- the attempt made by a player to demonstrate a set (move? call? attempt?)
- the different types within a feature (variations?)

What are the technical terms used in card games, such as Set?

Comment: Have you googled *set* or looked at the wiki for it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_game

Comment: @spiceyokooko I think he has, he linked to it.

Comment: randomblue, Thank you for the question, but this would be a better fit for our **[Board and Card Games](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq)** site. This has little to do with learning the English language, and more about the accepted terminology used for a game.

Comment: @randomblue: unfortunately, migration is not an option while the site is still in private beta.

Comment: @randomblue Sorry about the typo. I already fixed it. It's my job to handle issues of moderation, especially so early in a site's launch while the community is still forming. This is off topic. Migration isn't the preferred solution unless there is considerable content to be saved. It orphans the users *not* on that site, and voting is out of context. It's preferred just to ask the question again.